# C++ If statement logic

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am currently taking a class in c++ and for one of our assignments I am having a little trouble with for some reason.

> Asks a user the total amount of their purchase in a store and
>   calculates their  discount based on the following rule:
>
> - If they spend $50, give them a 10% discount
> - If they spend $75, the discount is 15%
> - If they spend $100, the discount is 25%
> - Finally, if they spend $250 or more, they get 40% off.
> - Display the amount of their purchase, subtract the discount and display the result.

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    double amount,discount=0.0;
    cout<<"Enter the total amount of your purchase: $";
    cin>>amount;
    cout<<endl;

    if (amount<50)
        cout<<"You do not recieve a discount"<<endl;
    else if(amount<=50.0)
    {
        discount=0.1*amount;
        cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
        amount=amount*0.9;
        cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(amount<=75.0)
    {
        discount=0.15*amount;
        cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
        amount=amount*0.85;
        cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(amount<=100.0)
    {
        discount=0.25*amount;
        cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
        amount=amount*0.75;
        cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(amount<=250.0)
    {
        discount=0.4*amount;
        cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
        amount=amount*0.6;
        cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not receiving the correct numbers for example if I enter 74 it will give me 11.1
I feel like it is a simple reason why I am getting the wrong number but I am not sure why

Comment: If you indent the code, the logic will be easier to follow.

Comment: You need to reverse the logic. Do `if (amount >250){} else if (amount > 100){} … else {}`. The else will refer to the lowest discount.

Comment: You don't need to return at the end of every else clause.

Comment: in addition to what @NeilKirk said, why are you repeating all that output code? just put that stuff at the end and take out the returns...

Comment: @NeilKirk I fixed it. I typed the wrong thing.

Comment: @BradAllred -good point, I will make the changes. Thank you

Comment: @royhowie: Reversing the `<=` to `>` won't fix the problem, that will make it worse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main() {

double amount,discount=0.0;
cout<<"Enter the total amount of your purchase: $";
cin>>amount;
cout<<endl;

if (amount<50)
cout<<"You do not recieve a discount"<<endl;
else if(amount>=250.0)//250 or more
{
    discount=0.4*amount;
    cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
    amount=amount*0.6;
    cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
    return 0;
}


else if(amount>=100.0)
{
    discount=0.25*amount;
    cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
    amount=amount*0.75;
    cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
    return 0;
}

else if(amount>=75.0)
{
    discount=0.15*amount;
    cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
    amount=amount*0.85;
    cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
    return 0;
}
else if(amount>=50.0)
{
    discount=0.1*amount;
    cout<<"Discount: $"<<discount<<endl;
    amount=amount*0.9;
    cout<<"Total Amount: $"<<amount<<endl;
    return 0;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at one of your problem cases:

```
else if(amount<=50.0)
```

The 10% discount applies to people who spend at least $50 - the test used above will limit it to people who spend at most $50  (let's ignore for the time being that people who spend less than $50 will already have been filtered out by the previous `if`).

To create an `if` clause that decides if a person should have the 10% discount, you need to model the mathematical expression:

```
$50.00 <= amount < $75.00
```

That expression translates naturally into the following C code:

```
else if (50.00 <= amount && amount < 75.00)
```

If you like, you can leave out the first part of that expression - it gets handled by the `if`  prior to this else clause:

```
if (amount < 50.00)
    cout<<"You do not receive a discount"<<endl;
else if (amount < 75.00)
    // etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your set of conditionals doesn't match the problem statement. When you request `74`, that's going to match the `(amount <= 75)`, which is going to apply the wrong discount.

The ranges that you are looking for are actually these:

```
if (amount < 50) {
    // No Discount
}
else if (amount < 75) {
    // 10% Discount
}
else if (amount < 100) {
    // 15% Discount
}
else if (amount < 250) {
    // 25% Discount
}
else {
    // 40% Discount
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`float` and `double` variables should not be compare with `==`, `<=`, `>=`, you should use epsilon. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

For me, your if else conditions should look like below.

```
if (0 > amount)
{
   // ERROR
   return;
}
else if (50.0 > amount)
{
   // No discount
   return;
}
else if (75.0 > amount)
{
   // 10% discount
   return;
}
else if (100.0 > amount)
{
   // 15% discount
   return;
}
else if (250.0 > amount)
{
   // 25% discount
   return;
}
else
{
   // 40% discount
   return;
}
```

Comment: 100% unrelated to the bug, and 100% unnecessary for this case.  Quoting from your link: "Never use `==` to compare two floating point numbers.". But the OP is _not_ using `==` to compare two floating point numbers.

Comment: Yes, he is not using `==` but he is using `<=` to compare `double`. Is it right move? Secondly, my if-else statement is the same as I can see now above my post (+4 btw). Thirdly,  @user3363156 has written his if-else statement wrong in my opinion, so I wrote my one. I correct in my code for example `if (amount<50)` ... `else if(amount<=50.0)` .... @user3363156 has wrong ranges for each discounts, what is corrected in my code. I think your comment is simply unfair.

Comment: Yes.  floating point numbers work (more or less) as expected for `<, <=, >=, >`.  You are right that your code is correct and good.

Comment: The downvote is based strictly on this: _float and double variables should not be compare with ==, <=, >=, you should use epsilon._ That is blatantly false.